Cannot sign into Chrome browser
Just did a clean installation of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my new ASUS TUF A15 laptop. I am simply unable to sign into the Chrome browser or sync bookmarks, etc. Very annoying. the directions state to click on the profile, and then sign in. Well, there is no option for that. How do I get to be able to sign into the Chrome browser and sync?

Suggest you look at Chrome help for this.

Please double check that you are actually using Google Chrome and not its open source base, Chromium. Some years ago, Google removed the feature to sync with a Google account from Chromium and made it exclusive to Google Chrome.
